# Lat Long in reverse position in mongodb .net core

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, point, geo

When I post to DB in one place the lat long values are in right positions i.e "latitude": "value of latitude" and "longitude": "value of longitude" but the values which the MongoDB driver package, geojsonpoint's latitude, and longitude values are posting reversed i.e "latitude": "value of longitude" and "longitude": "value of longitude"   and in the other,

```
public class eProperty
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        .
        .
        .
        .
        [JsonProperty("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates> Location
        { get; set; }
        public void SetLocation(double lon, double lat) => SetPosition(lat, lon);

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

        private void SetPosition(double lon, double lat)
        {
            Latitude = lat;
            Longitude = lon;
            Location = new GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates>(
                new GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates(lat, lon));
        }

    }

public ePropertyReadModel Create(ePropertyCreateModel propertyCreateModel)
    {
        var eProperty = MapCreateModelToDBModel(propertyCreateModel);

        eProperty.SetLocation(propertyCreateModel.Latitude, propertyCreateModel.Longitude);
        eProperty.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

        eProperty = _repo.Create(eProperty);

        return MapDbModelToReadModel(eProperty);
    }
```

This is create mapping for UI

```
private eProperty MapCreateModelToDBModel(ePropertyCreateModel propertyModel)
    {
        var eProperty = new eProperty();
        eProperty.Address = propertyModel.Address;
        eProperty.Images = propertyModel.Images;
        eProperty.Latitude = propertyModel.Latitude;
        eProperty.Longitude = propertyModel.Longitude;
        return eProperty;
    }
```

Data in DB look like this. Please take a look on lat and long in both places.

```
[
{
"Status": "available",
    "Price": 72400000.0,
    "Images": "https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/54832guTA4yhbiQ",
    "Latitude": 33.685833,
    "Longitude": 72.835843,
    "Location": {
        "Coordinates": {
            "Values": [
                33.685833,
                72.835843
            ],
            "Longitude": 33.685833,
            "Latitude": 72.835843
        },
        "Type": 7,
        "BoundingBox": null,
    },
    "CreatedDate": "2022-01-04T05:44:55.97Z"
},
```

Comment: It's [documented](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_GeoJsonObjectModel_GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates__ctor.htm) to be constructed with `long, lat`. Not `lat, long`.

Comment: Do you mean here is a mistake.
Location = new GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates>(
                new GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates(lat, lon));

Comment: Thank you! You helped me.